# How to avoid raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python/selenium and i try to do a webscrapper.I am trying to get the names of the teams out of this. This is the code I am using:

```
url_getsbet = 'https://online.getsbet.ro/sports'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url_getsbet)

matches_sb = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.Details__Participants")))
print(matches_sb)
```

and this is the html where the element is located

```
<span class="Details__Group">
  <span class="Details__Participants">
    <span class="Details__Participant Details__Participant--Home">
      <span class="Details__ParticipantName">Benfica</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Details__Participant Details__Participant--Away">
      <span class="Details__ParticipantName">Club Brugge</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div class="Score Score--1"></div>
</span>
```

And it causes this error:
line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace).

I don't realise what's causing this error.

Thank you and you help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 99.9% of the time, you are just using a wrong css or xpath selector, that the driver is not finding anything for 10 seconds.

Comment: you could try with EC.presence_of_element_located, or find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: i am using this selector (EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.Details__Participants"))) but idk what s wrong

Comment: As an update, i tried to locate any span and it got me some, but not the one i wanted, is it possible that the website is protected against this?

Answer (score 1):

The desired elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

    ```
    driver.get("https://online.getsbet.ro/sports")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.cookie_consent_btn"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#SportsBookIframe")))
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.Details__Participants")))])
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['Tottenham\nAC Milan', 'Bayern Munich\nPSG', 'Benfica\nClub Brugge KV', 'Chelsea\nBorussia Dortmund', 'Lazio\nAZ Alkmaar', 'UTA Arad\nFcsb', 'Petrolul\nUniversitatea Craiova', 'Voluntari\nFC Argeș', 'CS Mioveni\nChindia Târgoviște', 'Sepsi\nCFR Cluj', 'SCM Gloria Buzau\nFC Unirea 2004 Slobozia', 'Steaua București\nBaia Mare', 'Brentford\nFulham', 'Liverpool\nMan Utd', 'Nottm Forest\nEverton', 'Osasuna\nCelta Vigo', 'Rayo Vallecano\nAthletic Bilbao', 'Real Betis\nReal Madrid', 'Real Valladolid\nEspanyol', 'Barcelona\nValencia', 'Montpellier\nAngers', 'Rennes\nMarseille', 'Troyes\nMonaco', 'Reims\nAC Ajaccio', 'Lyon\nLorient']
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://online.getsbet.ro/sports")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='cookie_consent_btn']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='SportsBookIframe']")))
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='Details__Participants']")))])
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['TottenhamAC Milan', 'Bayern MunichPSG', 'BenficaClub Brugge KV', 'ChelseaBorussia Dortmund', 'LazioAZ Alkmaar', 'UTA AradFcsb', 'PetrolulUniversitatea Craiova', 'VoluntariFC Argeș', 'CS MioveniChindia Târgoviște', 'SepsiCFR Cluj', 'SCM Gloria BuzauFC Unirea 2004 Slobozia', 'Steaua BucureștiBaia Mare', 'BrentfordFulham', 'LiverpoolMan Utd', 'Nottm ForestEverton', 'OsasunaCelta Vigo', 'Rayo VallecanoAthletic Bilbao', 'Real BetisReal Madrid', 'Real ValladolidEspanyol', 'BarcelonaValencia', 'MontpellierAngers', 'TroyesMonaco', 'RennesMarseille', 'ReimsAC Ajaccio', 'LyonLorient']
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)